# Can a Sculpt brush's texture change automatically with each use?

Tags: sculpting

Is it possible to have an anchored type sculpting brush that changes the texture it uses randomly from a pre stablished selection of images?

I want to make things like bullet holes or scratches on a surface and I wonder if it's possible for the texture to change automatically each time I place the brush down instead of me having to change the texture manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this answer helps you or not.

First of all, I do not know if there exist a setting that changes brush texture automatically at each stroke except for python scripts.

Since I'm no python expert I would describe a way in which you can attain those results close enough.

step1 : select all the images you want, while selecting/importing the Image in the Image texture panel (This should import the textures in a image sequence format)

[image]

something like this (tweak the settings as shown)

step 2: Hit the spacebar twice (to play the sequence and refresh the textures) after each anchored stroke.

[image]

this is useful if you want to add some random detail.

I might update this if I find a better way in future or someone might answer that way :D

Comment: I've tried this but when I select multiple images it doesn't load them as an Image sequence. When I change the setting to image sequence it says 'Can't load image' for anythign other than the first one.
Is this only n 2.93?

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work. Just needed to have the images named properly and refresh while on the texture tab. Thanks a lot.